# How to update variable product stock status with code

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have the product id:- `$posts`. Now i have to change product variable variation stock to outofstock using code.I have bellow snippet code but it's not updating the variation stock of the product. so any one tell me how to do this.

```
$children = get_posts( array(
      'post_parent'   => $posts,
      'posts_per_page'=> -1,
      'post_type'   => 'product_variation',
      'fields'     => 'ids',
      'post_status'  => 'publish'
    ) );

    $out_of_stock_staus = 'outofstock';

    foreach ( $children as $child_id ) {
        echo $child_idss= $child_id->ID;
      echo $child_stock_status = get_post_meta( $child_id, '_stock_status', true );
     // $child_stock_status = $child_stock_status ? $child_stock_status : 'instock';
        //wc_update_product_stock_status( $product_id, $stock_statusss );
        update_post_meta( $child_id, '_stock_status', wc_clean( $out_of_stock_staus ) );
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most parts of your code were unnecessary.

Assuming you get the correct set of posts with your `get_posts()`, you can just loop through those posts, and update the meta.

You also had a confusion of the variables and objects in your loop, and you tried to update/get information passing a post object instead of an `$id`.

```
$children = get_posts( array(
    'post_parent'   => $posts,
    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
    'post_type'   => 'product_variation',
    'post_status'  => 'publish'
) );

$out_of_stock_staus = 'outofstock';

foreach ( $children as $thischild ) {

    update_post_meta( $thischild->ID, '_stock_status', wc_clean( $out_of_stock_staus ) );

}
```